# Sending a byte array over REST which contains encrypted data

Tags: java, aes, public-key-encryption

I use the following code to encrypt some data and I want to move the decryption code to a server so need to send the cipherData (which is a byte [] array ) to my server over REST

```
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger("blah");
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger("blah");

        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);

        KeyFactory encryptfact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = encryptfact.generatePublic(keySpec);

        String dataToEncrypt = "Hello World";

        /**
         * Encrypt data
         */
        Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = encrypt.doFinal(dataToEncrypt.getBytes());

        System.out.println("cipherData: " + new String(cipherData));

        /**
         * Decrypt data
         */
        BigInteger privatemodulus = new BigInteger("blah");
        BigInteger privateexponent = new BigInteger("blah");

        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(privatemodulus, privateexponent);

        PrivateKey privateKey = encryptfact.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] decData = decrypt.doFinal(cipherData);

        System.out.println(new String(decData));
```

This works fine.

I was hoping I could just create a new String with the cipherData as a parm

When I try this with the above example I get the following error

```
byte[] decData = decrypt.doFinal(new String(cipherData).getBytes());

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:308)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:255)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at com.test.EncryptTest.main(EncryptTest.java:52)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was hoping I could just create a new String with the cipherData as a parm

No. `cipherData` is arbitrary binary data. It's *not* encoded text, which is what the various String constructors expect. (As an aside, you should almost *never* call the `String.getBytes()` or `new String(byte[])` which don't specify an encoding. Always specify an appropriate encoding, which will depend on the situation.)

Either transmit the data *as* binary data instead of going through text at all, or use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to safely encode the binary data as text first, then decode it from Base64 to binary again later before decrypting. There's a [public domain Base64 encoder](http://iharder.net/base64) which is easy to use.

Comment: Something like http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html ?

Comment: @user1177292: Yes, that would work fine - or see the link in my answer for another one which is just a single source file you can include in your project.